# Rails how to rewrite old form from Rails 1.2 to rails 3.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this Rails 1.2.6 form:

```
<%= form_tag(:action => "login_in_user") %>
 <p>
          <label for="header">Username</label>
          <%= text_field("user", "name") %>       
          </p>          
         <p>
          <label for="header">Password</label>
          <%= password_field("user", "password") %>                
          </p>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <%= write_flash_notice(:label => true)%>
          <%= error_messages_for 'user' %>
 <p>
          <label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>          
    <%= submit_tag("login") %>     
           </p>
<%= end_form_tag %>
```

I have really tried to rewrite this wihhout luck using form_for(:login_in_user)

How should I rewrite it?

**UPDATE** - Rails§! Had of course forgot the   `<%= yield %>` in layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a @user instance present? If so:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => { :action => :login_in_user } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <%= error_messages_for :user %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :submit %>
    <%= f.submit :login %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```